# NSClassFromString not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here is an issue I have with this case of code:

```
let entityTypeDico = ["entityTypeOne": arrayOne, "entityTypeOneTwo": arrayTwo,
                      "entityTypeThree": arrayThree, "entityTypeFour": arrayFour];

for (entityName, arrayItem) in entityTypeDico {
    for x in arrayItem {
      /*do something with x and arrayItem
      I need to use the class of entityName */
      //To get it I tried to use some code like:
      NSClassFromString(entityName) // But it does not work.
    }
}
```

entityTypeOne, ..... entityTypeFour are names of CoreData entities,
arrayOne, ..... arrayFour are some kind of arrays (not so important for the question).

What exact code do I need to use to get hold of the type of each entity inside the loop?

Comment: It might help to know... If you *do* get a valid return from `NSClassFromString()`, what are you trying to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I ended up by finding after a number of experiments.
It works and does what I want. I hope it will be useful to some other people too.

```
let entityTypeDico = ["entityTypeOne": arrayOne, "entityTypeOneTwo": arrayTwo,
                      "entityTypeThree": arrayThree, "entityTypeFour": arrayFour];

// "entityTypeXYZ" is a class name (subclass of NSManagedObject)
// arrayXYZ is some array (not so important for the question)

for (entityName, arrayItem) in entityTypeDico {
    for x in arrayItem {
      /*do something with x and arrayItem
      I need to use the class of entityName */
      //To get it I tried to use some code like:
      NSClassFromString(entityName) // But it did not work.
      // Here is what finally worked for me:
      ((NSClassFromString("\(entityName)")) as! NSManagedObject.Type)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second for loop doesnt make sense. Can you try?

```
for (entityName, arrayItem) in entityTypeDico {
    NSClassFromString("YourProjectName.\(entityName)")
}
```

**Edit 1**

Currently I am working on a project where I used NSClassFromString. And that is how I used it in my code.

In my main class I use:

```
let carClass = NSClassFromString("MyProjectName.\(self.selectedBrand)\(self.selectedModel)") as! NSObject.Type
_ = carClass.init()
```

where selectedBrand and selectedModel are picked by the user.

In the car class, I have an init function

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    // My codes here like initializing webview

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: My second for loop makes sense because arrayItem is in fact an array, but it is quite irrelevant to the question, so you are right we can consider it as a nonsense here.

Comment: I have already tried:
let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String;
NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(entityName)");
Which is equivalent to what you suggest but it does not work.

Comment: Could there be a typo in your code like: NSClassFromString("\\(namespace).\\(entityName)") instead of NSClassFromString("(namespace).(entityName)");

Comment: I have slightly modified the syntax and it now works. I should post my answer sometime soon, since it may useful to others.